# Trying to factorise

Tags: python, python-3.x

This tries to factorise, I have made the code in this way as I intend to change some features to allow for more functionality but what I want to know is why my results for xneg and xpos are both 0.

```
import math
sqrt = math.sqrt
equation = input("Enter the equation in the form x^2 + 5x + 6 :  ")
x2coe = 0
xcoe = 0
ecoe = 0
counter = -1
rint = ''

for each in range(len(equation)+1):
    if equation[each] == 'x':
        break
    x2coe = int(equation[each])
    counter = counter + 1

for each in range(len(equation)):
    if equation[each] == 'x':
        break
    xcoe = int(equation[counter + 5:counter + 6])

ecoe = int(equation[len(equation) - 1])

if x2coe == 0:
        x2coe = 1
if xcoe == 0:
        xcoe = 1

xpos = (-xcoe+sqrt((xcoe**2)-4*(x2coe*ecoe)))/(2*x2coe)
xneg = (-xcoe-sqrt((xcoe**2)-4*(x2coe*ecoe)))/(2*x2coe)

print("Possible Solutions")
print("-----------------------------------------------")
print("X = {0}".format(xpos))
print("X = {0}".format(xneg))
print("-----------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the error? What is the expected result?

Comment: One issue I can see right away is that you are dividing only by 2, instead of `2*x2coe`. It should be `.../(2*x2coe)` or `.../2/x2coe`.

Comment: `for each in range(len(equation)):` - **DO NOT DO THIS**. You should just be using `for character in equation`

Comment: Actually, that second loop makes no sense at all. All it does is set `xcoe` to the same value over and over again, an arbitrary number of times

Comment: I'd recommend using simpler variable names.  Since we all learned the quadratic equation using Ax^2+Bx+C as the equation being factored, I'd recommend sticking with A, B, and C.  It will make your code more readable.  (Of course if Python has different naming conventions, just use a b and c.)

Comment: Also in order to avoid errors being thrown to the user, make a variable for determinant -- D = B**2-4*A*C -- and check whether it's positive or negative.  If negative, there are no Real solutions and  MAYBE you could invert the sign and report it in terms of i.

Comment: I meant "discriminant" -- and Python does actually support complex numbers.  Do something like this:
disc = B**2-4*A*C

if(disc>=0):
    sqrt = math.sqrt
else:
    sqrt = cmath.sqrt
xpos = (-B+sqrt(disc))/(2*A)
xneg = (-B-sqrt(disc))/(2*A);
print("Possible Solutions: {{{0},{1}}}".format(xpos,xneg))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your x2coe and xcoe variables are both 0 when you reach the computations for xpos and xneg.  You would have received a division by zero, except for what looks like another problem.  The xpos & xneg expressions look like the quadratic formula, but you are dividing by 2 and then multiplying by x2coe at the end.  Multiplication and division have equal precedence and group from left to right, so you need to use one of:

```
xpos = (-xcoe+sqrt((xcoe**2)-4*(x2coe*ecoe)))/(2*x2coe) # one way to fix
xneg = (-xcoe-sqrt((xcoe**2)-4*(x2coe*ecoe)))/2/x2coe # another, slower way
```

I suggest that you get the "business" logic of your program debugged first, and just input the three coefficients as a tuple or list.

```
x2coe, xcoe, ecoe = eval(input("Enter coefficients of ax^2+bx+c as a,b,c: "))
```

When your factoring code gives the results you want, then go back and put in a fancy input handler.

Hint: `import re`.  Regular expressions are a good tool for simple parsing like this.  (You'll need something even fancier if you want to handle parentheses/brackets/braces some day.)  Take a look at the how-to document at http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html first, and also bookmark the re module documentation at http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, the reason I am using such a way to handle the input is because I made it myself as I have a very small knowledge of python at the moment and don't spend that much time learning. I will update the code and try and get this think working. Thanks.

Comment: @KieranLavelle You're welcome.  The reason I for that suggestion is that it's easier to solve two simple problems than one complicated one.  That's particularly true when you're learning a new language or API.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that you're hard-coding how long you think each coefficient should be: 1 digit.  You should use another function that would make it more flexible.  Any of the coefficients could be blank, in which case A or B should be assumed to be 1 and C should be assumed to be 0.

Hopefully this will help:

```
p = re.compile('\s*(\d*)\s*x\^2\s*\+\s*(\d*)\s*x\s*\+\s*(\d*)\s*')
A, B, C = p.match(equation).group(1, 2, 3)
print(A, B, C)
```

All of the instances of `\s*` are to allow for flexibility in input, so spaces don't kill you.

Comment: TIL `.group` takes multiple arguments

Comment: Also, `\s*\s*` is equivalent to `\s*`

Comment: I don't understand this but I am going to totally re-do the code today so I will work this out and put it into the newer version later today. I intentionally assumed the coefficients were 1 character long at the start till I had the final details sorted out to decrease the complexity of my rather poor input handling.

Comment: @UFL1138 I think you need to use r'\s...etc' to prevent those backslashes from being treated as string escapes.

Comment: @KieranLavelle These are the "regular expressions" I mentioned.  They're not all that complicated. Read the HOWTO article at http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html

Comment: @Mike Housey I could be missing something but it worked for me when I ran it.

Comment: Oh I see. Unlike Java, Python doesn't complain if there's an 'escape sequence'it doesn't recognize. It just leaves it as two separate characters. I just didn't happen to use any valid escape sequences.

Comment: @UFL1138 TIL strikes again! :^) I just learned that, too.  I still think it's better to use r'' or r"" on these, so that the regex always looks like it's supposed to...but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Actually I don't really have any experience with Python; I downloaded IDLE and got the example working with regex.  I'm pretty good at Java, and I know you have to double-slash everything there but the examples for Python didn't seem to have any of those.  Thanks for the r'string' tip.